# How To Click on one of these buttons in the image(Notification) using python selenium

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

i told myself i can do it by click-Right in the button then copy the xpath and code it with click...
But i found out this is not working like that because when i click-right nothing happen

[image]

Comment: Don't scrape Facebook. Use the API.

Comment: CAN I KNOW WHY PLEASE ?

Comment: Because Facebook Terms of Service doesn't allow it. Also scraping will stop working every time Facebook changes their website which happens several times a day.